# Remove/hide One Drive folder in file explorer

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server, group-policy

I have a mapped drive which redirects user's local folders to the mapped drive. I wish to hide the One Drive so users utilize the mapped drive instead of the OneDrive.

I've attempted to uninstall One Drive but the shortcut is still accessible through file explorer. Changing the registry path of "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ {Customer OneDrive Path} > *System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree*" to 0.

Changing the registry to the above path works for 1 user, I wish to apply to all the users accessing the server which I implement in Group policy management console > Computer configuration > Preferences > Registry (Update and Delete action). I implemented the same for User Configuration but both tests didn't hide/remove the OneDrive folder.

Additional facts:

- Servers are hosted in a AVD (Azure Virtual Desktop) environment.
- Policies implemented are done through GPO (Group Policy object) only and are assigned to the respective OUs (Organizational Units).
- The server is using an image without the One Drive application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*("I've attempted to uninstall One Drive but the shortcut is still accessible through file explorer.")*

Merely uninstalling OneDrive may not suffice; it's imperative to disable all synchronizations beforehand. Upon signing into OneDrive *(and, unfortunately, it is necessary to sign-in in the process of installing Windows 11)*, Microsoft automatically redirects the Desktop, Documents, and Pictures folders to specific OneDrive paths:

1. *C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Desktop*
2. *C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Documents*
3. *C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Pictures*

Failure to deactivate these synchronizations prior to uninstalling OneDrive results in persistent redirection. This is evident when creating an empty .txt file on the Desktop and examining its path.

--

How to fix:

If OneDrive has been uninstalled without prior synchronization deactivation, reinstall OneDrive. Use the program to disable all synchronization including for Desktop, Documents, and Pictures folders. This action results in the original non-OneDrive paths and with empty content of these folders! so, it's advisable to create a backup before the deactivation.

1. *C:\Users\Username\Desktop*
2. *C:\Users\Username\Documents*
3. *C:\Users\Username\Pictures*

and only after ensuring via the file explorer that the folders reverted to "C:\Users\Username", proceed to uninstall OneDrive and delete the "C:\Users\Username\OneDrive" directory:

[image]

Comment: Hi Amit, when you meant by "Use the program to disable all synchronization including for Desktop, Documents, and Pictures folders", are you referring to the program as the OneDrive app?

Comment: @tehais, yes, I refer to the OneDrive app.

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is per-user – you cannot alter it through Computer Configuration, as that's applied outside a user context. (You could say "before anyone has a chance to log in".) Such changes need to be done through User Configuration.

("Loopback GPO" can be enabled to allow user GPOs to be pulled from computer OUs, if necessary, but it still needs to be User Configuration.)

More specifically, HKCR is a merged view of system HKLM\Software\Classes and user HKCU\Software\Classes. You should directly edit the latter, i.e. under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have a clarification . I'll first enable the loopback GPO (replace) and then add the registry path in group policy for User configuration, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 Home, so no access to Group Policy editor, but the registry key:

- `[HKCU|HKLM]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum`

can hide folders nomally displayed in the Navigation Pane.

The entries under this key are CLSID-named DWORD values. I've successfully hidden This PC, Libraries, OneDrive Personal, etc. A value of `1` hides the folder. A value of zero (or deleting an entry) allows it to show. Here, I've hiddon OneDrive for just my profile:

[image]

I don't know where you'll find this in the policy editor, or the CLSID for OneDrive Business, but hopefully this is enough to help.

Comment: hey, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find my customer's OneDrive ID with the suggested registry path. Based on my findings, I'm able to find the OneDrive ID based on these 2 paths [HKCU\Software\Classes] and [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID]

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to *find* the ID under the `NonEnum` key unless *you or the Group Policy Editor created it*! ***Create*** the key, sign out and back in, check **Explorer**.